# Redirecting output to file in batch file requires closing? (batch script)

Tags: windows, batch-file, echo, file-handling

In a batch script redirecting the output to a file like so

```
set "output=C:\output.txt"
echo Blah blah blah. >> %output%
```

Is it required that the file is closed after the redirection of writing stuff to it is completed (similar to the approach in other programming languages)?

I have tried searching for related information online but could not find something on it; I assume the fact that most scripts are closed after they finish their tasks (commands) is maybe the reason why.

But if say a script is to run in an **endless loop** where a different `output` file is written (e.g. by appending the time to the `output` file name) or if new output is constantly being redirected to the same `output` file, could the "*not closing of the file*" potentially lead to problems, memory or other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't have to close any file handles in batch scripts. You don't know the file handle value so you could not even close it if you wanted to.

On Windows, all open kernel handles are closed when a process ends/crashes but since a batch file is interpreted by cmd.exe without starting a new cmd.exe process in most cases, it cannot take advantage of the automatic handle cleanup and will manually close the file handle after each redirected operation.